# Should I ignore the left out samples or insert padding during batch processing data

Tags: python, loss-functions, tensorflow, numpy

So I'm trying to use Weighted Binary Cross Entropy Function. I'm trying to calculate the weights for each class. I have 14 of them them in the target variable.

I'm using the following function for calculating the weights.

```py
def compute_class_freqs(labels):
    """
    Args:
        labels (np.array): matrix of labels, size (num_examples, num_classes)
    Returns:
        positive_frequencies (np.array): array of positive frequences for each
                                         class, size (num_classes)
        negative_frequencies (np.array): array of negative frequences for each
                                         class, size (num_classes)
    """
    N = len(labels)
    print(labels)
    positive_frequencies = np.sum(labels, axis=1) / N
    negative_frequencies = 1 - positive_frequencies

    return positive_frequencies, negative_frequencies
```

I'm taking BATCH_SIZE as 32. Since the total data size is 112121, which is obviously not a multiple of 32 or any power of 2. There are some samples that get left in the last batch that are not 32. Hence I get this broadcasting errors from numpy.

Should I ignore the last batches in calculating the weight. Or is it significant that I should do so?

I'm using tensroflow 2.11.0 in python 3.9.16

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159034/what-if-the-sample-size-is-not-divisible-by-batch-size-in-keras-model) help?